GraalVM + Native Image: Can't register package-info.java for reflection
Is there a way (similar to classes, etc.) to make a package-info.java available at runtime of a native image build with GraalVM/native-image?
Problem
I try to migrate an application to Hibernate 6 + Spring Boot 3. It has a hibernate @FilterDef(name = "filterDeleted", ...) in a package-info.java, so that multiple entities can use it.
Starting the app with jvm works fine, building a native executable too. But on start an error is thrown:
Entity 'Contact' has a '@Filter' for an undefined filter named 'filterDeleted'
So I assume the package-info is not taken into account.
I've added a reflect-config.json pointing to the package-info directly as described here: github/oracle/graal but that doesn't fix the issue.
(I made sure the config file is recognized in the built process by renaming it and getting Error: The reflection configuration file "/Users/florian/Development/.../reflect-config.json" does not exist.)
We have another service built with Quarkus that uses the same entity model and does not have this problem when built natively.
Alternative Approach
I also tried to completely avoid the problem by adding the FilterDefinition programmatically (as described here: StackOverflow/defining-hibernate-5-filterdefinition-by-code), but to do this, I need to access the metadata at the correct phase of creation, as the validation of the entity model must not have taken place yet.

Simply including a class in the annotated package seemed to work for me in a small test project (standard Java; no Hibernate or Spring). You might want to try running your application with the tracing agent.

Thank you for your tips. With the agent, I was able to see that the package-info is being added. I can also access the annotation at the runtime of the native image. Interesting that Hibernate still doesn't recognize the @FilterDef.
